# Why so many linux-headers, even for absent images

Tags: kernel

I removed many of linux-images of 3.13.0-x versions, I left few versions installed.

```
~ > dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic                         3.13.0-83.127                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-85-generic                         3.13.0-85.129                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-86-generic                         3.13.0-86.131                                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-83-generic                   3.13.0-83.127                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic                   3.13.0-85.129                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-86-generic                   3.13.0-86.131                                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.86.92                                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-raring                        3.13.0.86.92                                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

As you can see there are only 3.13.0-x versions.

But also I have **a lot** of linux-headers for 3.**16**.0-x and 3.**19**.0-x versions.

```
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-85                               3.13.0-85.129                                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-85-generic                       3.13.0-85.129                                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-86                               3.13.0-86.131                                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-86-generic                       3.13.0-86.131                                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-43                               3.16.0-43.58~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-43-generic                       3.16.0-43.58~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-44                               3.16.0-44.59~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-44-generic                       3.16.0-44.59~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-45                               3.16.0-45.60~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-45-generic                       3.16.0-45.60~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-46                               3.16.0-46.62~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-46-generic                       3.16.0-46.62~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-48                               3.16.0-48.64~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-48-generic                       3.16.0-48.64~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-49                               3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-49-generic                       3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-50                               3.16.0-50.67~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-50-generic                       3.16.0-50.67~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-51                               3.16.0-51.69~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-51-generic                       3.16.0-51.69~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-52                               3.16.0-52.71~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-52-generic                       3.16.0-52.71~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-53                               3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-53-generic                       3.16.0-53.72~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-55                               3.16.0-55.74~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-55-generic                       3.16.0-55.74~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-56                               3.16.0-56.75~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-56-generic                       3.16.0-56.75~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-57                               3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-57-generic                       3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-59                               3.16.0-59.79~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-59-generic                       3.16.0-59.79~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-60                               3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-60-generic                       3.16.0-60.80~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-62                               3.16.0-62.83~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-62-generic                       3.16.0-62.83~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-67                               3.16.0-67.87~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-67-generic                       3.16.0-67.87~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-70                               3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-70-generic                       3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-71                               3.16.0-71.92~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
ii  linux-headers-3.16.0-71-generic                       3.16.0-71.92~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-22                               3.19.0-22.22~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-22-generic                       3.19.0-22.22~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-23                               3.19.0-23.24~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-23-generic                       3.19.0-23.24~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-25                               3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic                       3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-26                               3.19.0-26.28~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-26-generic                       3.19.0-26.28~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-28                               3.19.0-28.30~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-28-generic                       3.19.0-28.30~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-30                               3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-30-generic                       3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-31                               3.19.0-31.36~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic                       3.19.0-31.36~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-32                               3.19.0-32.37~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-32-generic                       3.19.0-32.37~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-33                               3.19.0-33.38~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-33-generic                       3.19.0-33.38~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-37                               3.19.0-37.42~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-37-generic                       3.19.0-37.42~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-39                               3.19.0-39.44~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-39-generic                       3.19.0-39.44~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-41                               3.19.0-41.46~14.04.2                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-41-generic                       3.19.0-41.46~14.04.2                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-42                               3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-42-generic                       3.19.0-42.48~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-43                               3.19.0-43.49~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-43-generic                       3.19.0-43.49~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-47                               3.19.0-47.53~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-47-generic                       3.19.0-47.53~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-49                               3.19.0-49.55~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-49-generic                       3.19.0-49.55~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-51                               3.19.0-51.58~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-51-generic                       3.19.0-51.58~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-56                               3.19.0-56.62~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-56-generic                       3.19.0-56.62~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-58                               3.19.0-58.64~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-58-generic                       3.19.0-58.64~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-59                               3.19.0-59.66~14.04.1                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-59-generic                       3.19.0-59.66~14.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                                 3.13.0.86.92                                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal                     3.13.0.86.92                                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-lts-raring                      3.13.0.86.92                                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-lts-saucy                       3.13.0.86.92                                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty                      3.13.0.86.92                                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic                      3.16.0.71.62                                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid                       3.19.0.59.42                                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
```

Why?

As I don't have 3.16 and 3.19 kernels, why does my system downloads and installs all these 3.16 and 3.19 headers?

Comment: Did you already try `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove no longer needed packages?

Comment: ...because you have the following metapackages: `linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic` and `linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid`, and they make sure you get the latest headers.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but they still exist

Comment: You can probably just remove them then. They won't show up like that in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, remove the metapackages for Utopic and Vivid:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid
```

...then the autoremove command should work:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

You may also want to try and remove all headers and kernels but the latest:

- dry run, prints out which packages are to be removed

  ```
   dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | grep -E "(image|headers|modules)" | xargs sudo apt-get --dry-run remove
  ```
- will remove all but the latest kernels, headers and modules

  ```
   dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | grep -E "(image|headers|modules)" | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
  ```

[Source and steps](http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/10/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-with-one-command/)